# Show that the operator $Ax(t)=\int_0^1 \frac{\cos(t\tau)}{|t-\tau|^\frac{1}{5}}x(\tau)d\tau$ is compact on $L_2[0,1]$.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

> I have to show that an operator $A:L_2[0,1]\rightarrow L_2[0,1]$ given by
> $$Ax(t)=\int_0^1 \frac{\cos(t\tau)}{|t-\tau|^\frac{1}{5}}\ x(\tau)\ d\tau$$
> is compact.

My idea is to show that it is uniformly limited and uniformly continuous, but I'm having difficulties checking the 2nd condition.

For it I take $t_1,t_2 \in [0,1]$ and compute $|Ax(t_1)-Ax(t_2)|$ and it goes:

$$|Ax(t_1)-Ax(t_2)|\leq\int_0^1|\frac{|t_2-\tau|^\frac{1}{5}\cos(t_1\tau) - |t_1-\tau|^\frac{1}{5}\cos(t_2\tau)}{|t_1-\tau|^\frac{1}{5}|t_2-\tau|^\frac{1}{5}}||x(\tau)|d\tau$$
$$\leq\text{max}_{\tau\in[0,1]}|x(\tau)|\int_0^1\frac{|t_2-\tau|^\frac{1}{5} + |t_1-\tau|^\frac{1}{5}}{|t_1-\tau|^\frac{1}{5}|t_2-\tau|^\frac{1}{5}}d\tau$$

I used triangular inequality and that $|\cos(t)|\leq1$ on the numerator.
The problem is that calculating this integral doesn't give me anything of the form $|t_1-t_2|$.

Comment: If you want to show that an operator is u-c why is your variable $t$ and not $x$?

Comment: The operator is in Hilbert-Schmidt class. Therefore it is compact.

Comment: How do yu check it's H-S? What is the basis of L2?

Comment: The operator is of the form $(Tf)(x)=\int\limits_0^1K(x,y)f(y)\,dy.$ If $\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1|K(x,y)|^2\,dx\,dy<\infty,$ the operator is H-S. Concerning the basis you can use  $e^{2\pi inx}$ for all integers $n.$